# Failing to compile DBD-Oracle-1.74 | Can't locate DBI.pm

Tags: perl

please help. I am trying to compile DBD-Oracle-1.74 Perl module and failing because obviously Perl **Can't locate DBI.pm**. But  DBI.pm  is there... I am using compiled under

```
/ag/smartcube/perl/bin/perl
```

and putting modules inside:

```
/ag/smartcube/perl/modules
```

directory. This system is cut off from internet, so no cpan or something like this is allowed. Only manual compilation.

```
 cd DBD-Oracle-1.74
    [root@dcpscp20907234 DBD-Oracle-1.74]# /ag/smartcube/perl/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALL_BASE=/ag/smartcube/perl/modules
    Can't locate DBI.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /ag/smartcube/perl/lib/5.10.0/x86_64-linux /ag/smartcube/perl/lib/5.10.0 /ag/smartcube/perl/lib/site_perl/5.10.0/x86_64-linux /ag/smartcube/perl/lib/site_perl/5.10.0 .) at Makefile.PL line 21.
    BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Makefile.PL line 21.
    [root@dcpscp20907234 DBD-Oracle-1.74]# find /ag/smartcube/ -iname DBI.pm
    /ag/smartcube/perl/modules/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux/Bundle/DBI.pm
    /ag/smartcube/perl/modules/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux/DBI.pm
    /ag/smartcube/perl/modules/DBI-1.633/lib/Bundle/DBI.pm
    /ag/smartcube/perl/modules/DBI-1.633/DBI.pm
    /ag/smartcube/perl/modules/DBI-1.633/blib/lib/Bundle/DBI.pm
    /ag/smartcube/perl/modules/DBI-1.633/blib/lib/DBI.pm
```

Please help, how to "tell" perl that DBI.pm is there.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to use `/ag/smartcube/perl/modules` in preference to one of the four directories where perl is already looking? I imagine you've installed `DBI` in the same way, but perl can't find it because the location isn't in `@INC`. You should reinstall `DBI` without setting `INSTALL_BASE`, and then `DBD::Oracle` should install correctly—also without `INSTALL_BASE`.

Comment: I have to install like 30 modules by hand somewhere [there is another Perl version on the system which I cannot touch ] so /ag/smartcube/perl/modules seems like good idea. Yes i installed all modules like this: /ag/smartcube/perl/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALL_BASE=/ag/smartcube/perl/modules. because I had no idea what else to do..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have installed modules using

```
/ag/smartcube/perl/bin/perl Makefile.PL
make
make test
make install
```

So that the modules you built would go into the locations where `/ag/smartcube/perl/bin/perl` expects to find them.

Also, there isn't a good reason to use 5.10.0 in preference to 5.10.1.

From [perldoc perl5101delta](https://metacpan.org/pod/perl5101delta#Selected-Bug-Fixes):

> - 5.10.0 inadvertently disabled an optimisation, which caused a measurable performance drop in list assignment, such as is often used to assign function parameters from `@_`. The optimisation has been re-instated, and the performance regression fixed.
> - And others ...